# JSON to custom object Trnslation. How to avoild null and Parsing error

Tags: android, gson, pojo

I am developing app in that there are lot of parameters in JSON response.To use this response in App, I use Plain Old Java Object(POJO). I am converting JSON to POJO using GSON library.  But problem is that some time conversation is not success full due to null and non parable value

I guess null can be handle by **new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()**
but main concern is what about non  Parceble value. Its really bad to check each paramter whether its Parcelable or not. So any good solution for that?